# Communicate over the fifo queue linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, unix

This is our task : Write three programs that communicate over the fifo queue. The first program will send the even numbers, the second program will send the odd numbers, and the third program will receive
the numbers and add them together. All processes should display the results of their work on the
screen.
I tried to solve it ,but my code is not working properly, maybe problem in 3 program , please help.
The first prog should send even numbers , second odd numbers , and third should receive and add this numbers together (sum). The first and second programs seem to perform their task but the third is not and freezes
My code:

//1 program

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


void prog1(int descriptor,char *fifo)
{

        int a=0;
        int i=0;
while (i!=10)
    {

            a+=2;
        descriptor = open(fifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(descriptor,&a, sizeof(a)+1);
        puts("");
  printf(" Even number : %d",a);
        close(descriptor);
        i++;

    }
}
int main()
{
    int descriptor;
    char * fifo = "/tmp/myfifo_file";
   mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
 prog1(descriptor,fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

//2 program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void prog2(int descriptor,char *fifo)
{

        int b=1;
        int i=0;

while (i!=10)
    {


        descriptor = open(fifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(descriptor, &b, sizeof(b)+1);
        puts("");
        printf("Odd number : %d",b);
        b+=2;
        close(descriptor);
       i++;

    }
}
int main()
{
    int descriptor;
    char * fifo = "/tmp/myfifo_file";
   mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
 prog2(descriptor,fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

//3 program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


void prog3(int descriptor,char *fifo)
{

        int *a;
        int *b;
        int i=0;
while (i!=10)
    {


        descriptor = open(fifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(descriptor,a, sizeof(a));
        close(descriptor);
        descriptor = open(fifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(descriptor,b, sizeof(b));
        close(descriptor);
        printf("Sum : %d",(*a)+(*b));
        i++;

    }
}
int main()
{
    int descriptor;
    char * fifo = "/tmp/myfifo_file";
   mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
 prog3(descriptor,fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is happening that is wrong? Please include more detail about what the code actually does, versus what it should do.

Comment: The first prog should send even numbers , second odd numbers , and third should receive and add this numbers together (sum). The first and second programs seem to perform their task but the third is not and freezes.

Comment: Yes there is a problem in prog3, you should put a pointer to a instead of a in the read function.

Comment: And this is actually a problem in prog1 and 2 as well, just read the function description. https://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Comment: descriptor = open(fifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(descriptor,*a, sizeof(a));
        close(descriptor);
        descriptor = open(fifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(descriptor,*b, sizeof(b));
        close(descriptor);
        printf("Sum : %d",a+b);
        i++;

Comment: in this  way or no ?

Comment: @HIPHOP Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification there instead of writing comments.

Comment: If you want to write the binary integer values in prog 1 and 2 you should use `write(descriptor, &b, sizeof(b));`. Your current program would interpret the number stored in `b` as an address and read from this address one byte more than the size of an `int`. This is undefined behavior. Your program will send garbage data or may even crash.  Some errors in your code should produce compiler warnings. Maybe you have to enable warnings. Please fix all warnings.

Comment: i did as you said , but the third program still does not display anything,now i change code in our question

Comment: You had the same error in prog3. Now you use uninitialized pointers `a` and `b` in prog3. Don't use `sizeof(b)+1`. This will also read a byte after the end of the memory that holds variable `b`. Compare with the code in my previous comment. **BTW:** There is no guarantee that prog3 will read one value from prog1 and one value from prog2. It may as well happen that e.g. prog1 writes all values first then prog2 writes all values.

Comment: the first program causes the compiler to output: "untitled.c:34:2: warning: ‘descriptor’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]"   Don't expect your code to work when it does not cleanly compile.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: in prog3, regarding: `int *a;
        int *b;`   these declare pointers to `int`, but no where in your program do you actually point those pointers to memory that your program owns

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: Note that prog3 fails to close and delete the FIFO after reading all the data.

Comment: strongly suggest reading all the data into two arrays in prog3, then walking through those arrays, summing and displaying the values

Comment: individual programs run asynchronously, so how is prog3 expected to differentiate the data when it does not even check to see which (odd/even) program a specific data comes from?

Comment: Please, when changing the code in the question, always include a 'edit' so we know what was changed

Answer (score 0):

Apart from errors using correct address and size of the data you want to read, the main error is that you should not repeatedly open and close the FIFO in the loop.

Opening a FIFO for reading or writing will block until the other end is also opened. So both prog1 and prog2 will wait until prog3 opens the FIFO for reading, and prog3 will wait until at least one of prog1 and prog2 opens the FIFO for writing.

Closing the FIFO on the writing end will cause an EOF condition on the reading end. Closing the FIFO on the reading end will cause a "broken pipe" error on the writing end.

The programs also lack error handling. `mkfifo`, `open`, `read`, `write`, `close` may return an error, `read` and `write` may also return a number of bytes less than what you wanted to read or write. This will probably not happen with your small amount of data in your example, but you will most probably notice this when you try to transfer large amounts of data.

Here are improved versions of your programs:

prog1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


void prog1(char *fifo)
{
    int descriptor;
    int a=0;
    int i=0;
    descriptor = open(fifo, O_WRONLY);
    while (i!=10)
    {

        a+=2;
        write(descriptor,&a, sizeof(a));
        printf("Even number %d : %d\n", i, a);
        i++;
    }
    close(descriptor);
}

int main(void)
{
    char * fifo = "/tmp/myfifo_file";
    mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
    prog1(fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

prog2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void prog2(char *fifo)
{
    int descriptor;
    int b=1;
    int i=0;

    descriptor = open(fifo, O_WRONLY);

    while (i!=10)
    {
        write(descriptor, &b, sizeof(b));
        printf("Odd number %d: %d\n", i, b);
        b+=2;
        i++;
    }
    close(descriptor);
}

int main(void)
{
    char * fifo = "/tmp/myfifo_file";
    mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
    prog2(fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

prog3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


void prog3(char *fifo)
{
    int descriptor;
    int a;
    int b;
    int i=0;

    descriptor = open(fifo, O_RDONLY);

    while (i!=10)
    {
        read(descriptor,&a, sizeof(a));
        read(descriptor,&b, sizeof(b));
        printf("Sum %d: %d + %d = %d\n", i, a, b, a+b);
        i++;
    }

    close(descriptor);
}

int main(void)
{
    char * fifo = "/tmp/myfifo_file";
    mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
    prog3(fifo);
    return 0;
}
```

When running the programs I get this (varying) output:

```
$ ./prog1&./prog2&
[1] 8410
[2] 8411
$ ./prog3         
Sum 0: 1 + 2 = 3
Odd number 0: 1
Even number 0 : 2
Odd number 1: 3
Sum 1: 3 + 4 = 7
Even number 1 : 4
Odd number 2: 5
Sum 2: 5 + 6 = 11
Odd number 3: 7
Even number 2 : 6
Odd number 4: 9
Even number 3 : 8
Sum 3: 7 + 9 = 16
Odd number 5: 11
Even number 4 : 10
Odd number 6: 13
Sum 4: 8 + 11 = 19
Even number 5 : 12
Odd number 7: 15
Sum 5: 10 + 13 = 23
Even number 6 : 14
Odd number 8: 17
Sum 6: 12 + 15 = 27
Odd number 9: 19
Even number 7 : 16
Sum 7: 14 + 17 = 31
Even number 8 : 18
Sum 8: 16 + 19 = 35
Even number 9 : 20
Sum 9: 18 + 20 = 38
[2]  + 8411 done       ./prog2
[1]  + 8410 done       ./prog1
```